# Which API does Windows Resource Monitor use?

Tags: windows, etw, resource-monitor

Windows Resource Monitor displays (among other things) which files on disk are currently accessed by which processes. And it does that in realtime. **How?**

I know that it probably uses ETW and that I can generate traces with tools like xperf. But how to get realtime information without having to start, stop and parse a trace file?

I need to programmatically access the data, i.e. from C# or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

w[OpenTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364089%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[ProcessTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364093%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[StopTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364119%28VS.85%29.aspx) can get the data in real-time as long as you know the provider GUID. They can run on Win2000 but you need to parse the raw data in your callback functions. To convert raw data into human-readable text, we need the TMF/MOF. Not sure if they are public though.

For Vista/Win7, there is a new set of TDH (Trace Data Helper) APIs (eg: TdhFormatProperty).
Scroll down a little of above links and you can see them. The good thing about TDH is they can parse the data for you (still need to provide TDH the TMF/MOF though).

I tried to write my own .etl to readable .txt program using Open/Process/StopTrace API (because I need to support XP). I found out it's quite difficult. The TMF file is not hard to interpret since it pure text. The hard thing is to decipher more than 50 different undocumented prinf-alike format-specifications' internal structures. So I gave up in the end and stick to the powerful [tracefmt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552974%28VS.85%29.aspx) provided in Microsoft WDK.